# Многопоточность и контролы

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, скажите мне пожалуйста, как обращаться из другого потока к контролам? Т.е. я знаю как можно это сделать (через делегаты, etc). Дак вот, как лучше обращаться к контролам, через делегаты или через переменные (т.е. переменные использовать как промежуточные участок, для хранения данных, а потом их записывать в контрол)?

Comment: ControlName.Invoke & ControlName.BeginInvoke();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неплохо было бы увидеть код, вызвавший проблемы. А вы принципиально не желаете использовать  [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx)? Вопросы взаимодействия с контролами ним замечательно решаются. Вот пример для WPF приложения - [ссылка на SkyDrive](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=0213B80F89787C58&id=213B80F89787C58%21131&sc=documents)

Answer (score 0):

Конечно использовать лучше классы делегатов. Но и в этом и в том варианте есть свои минусы.
Здесь - время на написание и отладку классов.
Там - потери по памяти (конечно зависит от программы, но как я понимаю это не просто какой то DM)

Comment: Не понял, что вы подразумеваете под DM? )

Comment: Возможно download-manager :]